# With SBT, how can I have two different proguard tasks with different settings?

Tags: scala, sbt, proguard

I have a single source tree from which I might build two different jars; call them JarA and JarB.

I am using the [sbt proguard plugin](https://github.com/adamw/xsbt-proguard-plugin) to run each jar through proguard. This plugin creates a task key called `proguard`.

I would like to make two task keys, say `proguardA` and `proguardB`, that build the respective jars. I have defined these task keys in project/Build.scala.

But, how do I use a different set of proguard options for each task? That is, how can I use a different value for the setting `proguardOptions`?

I have tried various permutations of task-scoped settings such as

```
proguardA <<= proguard in proguardA
proguardSettings in (proguard in proguardA) <<= ...
proguardSettings in proguardA <<= ...
```

etc

But none of these have taken effect.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to skin this cat, but I'd define two configurations in build.scala:

```
val ProguardA = config("proguarda") extend(Compile)
val ProguardB = config("proguardb") extend(Compile)
```

This will let you have a whole set of settings outside of `Compile`. As xsbt-proguard-plugin currently hardcodes the option to `Compile` configuration, we need to fix the `proguard` task.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import ProguardPlugin._

object Builds extend Build {
  val ProguardA = config("proguarda") extend(Compile)
  val ProguardB = config("proguardb") extend(Compile)

  val xProguardArgs = TaskKey[List[String]]("x-proguard-args")

  val appSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++       
    inConfig(ProguardA)(proguardSettings ++ Seq(
      proguard <<= (packageBin in Compile, xProguardArgs, baseDirectory) map { (_, args, bd) => proguardTask(args, bd) },
      xProguardArgs <<= proguardArgsTask,
      proguardOptions := Seq(keepMain("Test"))
    )) ++
    inConfig(ProguardB)(proguardSettings ++ Seq(
      proguard <<= (packageBin in Compile, xProguardArgs, baseDirectory) map { (_, args, bd) => proguardTask(args, bd) },
      xProguardArgs <<= proguardArgsTask, 
      proguardOptions := Seq(keepAllScala),
      minJarPath <<= (crossTarget, projectID, artifact, scalaVersion, artifactName) { (t, module, a, sv, toString) => t / toString(ScalaVersion(sv, CrossVersion binaryScalaVersion sv), module.copy(revision = module.revision + ".min-b"), a) asFile }
    )) ++
    Seq(
      // name := "foo",
      // libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies
    )

  lazy val app = Project("app", file("."), settings = appSettings)
}
```

You can now run it as `proguarda:proguard` or make a task `proguarda` that depends on `proguard in ProguardA`. Also you have to change the `minJarPath` or run `clean` each time to avoid cache picking up a wrong jar.